# Why is the Bootstrap Navbar is good in responsive mode but not displaying properly in smartphone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Website link: https://usamanavid.com/
[image: The Navbar is stuck a little outside the original width of the mobile.]

The Navbar is stuck a little outside the original width of the mobile
But it is responsive in desktop mode.

[image]

index.html

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top" id="sideNav">
  
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
      <span class="d-block d-lg-none">Muhammad Usama Navid</span>
      <span class="d-none d-lg-block">
        <img class="img-fluid img-profile rounded-circle mx-auto mb-2" src="images/profile.jpg" alt="">
      </span>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#experience">Experience</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Here is style.css

```
#sideNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing: .05rem;
    text-transform: uppercase
}


#sideNav .navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: none;
  outline-color : #d48a6e;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #sideNav {
        text-align: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 17rem;
        height: 100vh
    }}
```

On every phone size, it is a little bit more than the device width.

Comment: Check in developer console shift+ctrl+J in Chrome what element goes more that it should on right side ( I think that div with fonts ). Navbar display properly, but it bigger because of other element

Comment: First, the website is very slow you have an error in your console
Second, the issue that you added container class inside section that has id="skills"
just remove the class="container" that holds the 4 cards and it will be fixed